# Page layout two divs side by side: right scrollable only, left expandable to fit content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build this layout

[image]

I want :

- Two main divs side by side inside a wrapper div
- The wrapper should expand to 100% browser size
- the left div (banner) is fixed and overlayed, it will be like a vertical navigation container. However when the list of items exceeds what you can see in the browser without scrolling, the div expands its height
- The right div (content) has overflow:auto so that if its content exceeds its allowed height (browser height) you can scroll down to see the rest (all while left div is fixed).

I have been trying for a while for the best solution, this is what I came up with so far:

```
<style>
    html, body {
            height: auto;
        }
        #wrapper {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100%;

        }
        div#banner {
            width: 35%;
            float: left;
            padding-bottom: 1000px;
            margin-bottom: -1000px;
            overflow:hidden;
            height:100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74);
            z-index: 999;


        }
        div#content {
            width: 65%;
            float: left;
            background-color: grey;
            padding-bottom: 1000px;
            margin-bottom: -1000px;
            overflow:auto;
            background: blue;
            height:100%;
            color:white;
        }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="banner">
      <header>
            header content
        </header>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text2<br>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="">
        right
        text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

(**update**) https://jsfiddle.net/nze5ug5t/5/

How can I achieve this layout?

Comment: I don't really understand how you want the left div to behave. If it's fixed it will always stay the same *on the screen*, so even if it expand how do you scroll it?

Comment: The wrapper is going to scale no matter what. So what if you simply styled the wrapper to have a matching background color to your left sidebar? When the right side expands, the actual content on the left will stay static, but it will appear to be scaling. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nze5ug5t/2/).

Comment: @AvAvt the left div is fixed, it will have a list of items. what if this list expands beyond the browser's lower limit? then the scrolling that is applied to the page (based on the right div) will scroll a bit to show the rest of the left div. Or this is not feasible?

Comment: @AvAvt am not allowed to add more than 2 links. Check http://i.stack.imgur.com/mW6z0.png

Comment: With javascript, maybe. But pure css it's not possible.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ujg77o3r/6/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yes but 1 thing missing, the last 'text2' in the left div doesn't show. Is there a way to scroll it when scrolling the whole page? or this can only be done with javascript?

Comment: @AvAvt i upadted my jsfiddle link, how can i scroll the left div while scrolling the whole page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done without JavaScript. You need to check and apply different CSS rules depending on viewport height, left column height, right column height and scroll position. I guess it needs further testing, but this should do the trick:

```js
document.checkBanner = function() {
  var ch = $('.contentWrapper').innerHeight(),
    left = $('.left-banner-content'),
    lh = left.innerHeight(),
    s = $(document).scrollTop(),
    wh = $(window).height();
  if (wh > lh) {
    left.css({
      'top': s + 'px'
    })
  } else {
    if ((s + wh) > lh) {
      left.css({
        'top': (s + wh - lh - 20) + 'px'
      });
    } else {
      left.css({
        'top': 0
      });
    }
  }
  if ($(document).height() > ch) {
    $(document).scrollTop(ch - wh);
  }
}
$(document).scroll(function() {
  document.checkBanner();
});
$(document).resize(function() {
  document.checkBanner();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.left-banner {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 210px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 76, 0, .84);
  color: white;
}
.left-banner-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px 5px;
}
.contentWrapper {
  padding-left: 210px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.plafondchauffant.fr/modules/pm_advancedbackgroundchanger/uploads/slides/53d177879b0e2.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-banner">
    <div class="left-banner-content">
      <h3>This is left banner</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>some item</li>
        <li>some other item</li>
        <li>yet another item</li>
        <li>and another one</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>this is getting boring</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>This is content</h1>
      <p>Ennui pinterest kogi freegan +1, try-hard leggings pickled chillwave chartreuse raw denim 8-bit brooklyn. Cardigan sustainable marfa bitters vice. Humblebrag everyday carry leggings, shoreditch cold-pressed tacos before they sold out gastropub sriracha
        master cleanse distillery migas. Helvetica seitan humblebrag, jean shorts godard organic affogato. Mlkshk XOXO bicycle rights four dollar toast letterpress fap pitchfork salvia, forage meditation irony knausgaard next level. Pabst kogi echo park
        YOLO. Williamsburg ugh drinking vinegar messenger bag offal selvage.</p>

      <p>Actually selvage before they sold out, affogato dreamcatcher squid taxidermy chia cornhole deep v ethical meggings quinoa. Four dollar toast retro green juice, ramps squid truffaut etsy williamsburg artisan. Everyday carry ennui bicycle rights sustainable
        twee, umami portland cornhole blue bottle street art. 90's meh kale chips kitsch. Ennui tattooed pour-over, whatever small batch ethical disrupt YOLO four dollar toast echo park cronut keytar selvage tacos. You probably haven't heard of them master
        cleanse meditation single-origin coffee, ramps trust fund viral pitchfork letterpress yuccie marfa etsy. Keffiyeh mustache ramps put a bird on it slow-carb keytar.</p>

      <p>Locavore kickstarter freegan, pinterest authentic celiac portland four dollar toast affogato cray kogi hashtag direct trade. Dreamcatcher 90's trust fund, occupy fap fanny pack irony shoreditch readymade austin. Asymmetrical aesthetic iPhone, wayfarers
        try-hard dreamcatcher gluten-free kinfolk williamsburg hammock mumblecore sriracha. Migas farm-to-table pickled disrupt, plaid actually four loko bicycle rights vegan try-hard ramps banh mi. Trust fund portland intelligentsia organic. Etsy thundercats
        blue bottle, sartorial taxidermy hella fap flannel kogi seitan echo park. Drinking vinegar paleo pop-up synth roof party food truck.</p>

      <p>Cronut mixtape +1 YOLO helvetica bicycle rights. Offal polaroid authentic mixtape vinyl. Quinoa ramps banh mi ethical, banjo XOXO cornhole asymmetrical tumblr direct trade artisan salvia. Kitsch drinking vinegar gentrify tousled salvia, schlitz
        before they sold out slow-carb gluten-free. Offal viral pork belly plaid wayfarers single-origin coffee, green juice lo-fi kogi cardigan. Sartorial forage ugh pork belly, viral direct trade hashtag austin cronut celiac letterpress helvetica franzen
        chillwave. Vice chicharrones artisan next level pickled seitan.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE:
After fiddling with the rendering problems behind such a solution I realized there's no way someone didn't already code something similar. And I was right: here's [lockfixed](https://github.com/ymschaap/jquery-lockfixed/blob/master/jquery.lockfixed.js). Nicely wrapped as a jquery plugin. You should have googled your problem first :).

Cheers!

Comment: I did google my problem for hours, however I wasn't considering javascript I was checking if this can be done by CSS only. Thanks though for the help!

Comment: It took me a good while to realize it's not doable without JS, and I like to think I'm pretty seasoned with these sort of things. It's no biggie, I was trying to be funny.

Answer (score 0):

Any answer to your question will be heavily dependent on where all these elements will be living. However, is this what you're trying to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/efpygvxq/1/

The CSS is below. the HTML is too long. The salient point here is to make use of `position: absolute` with `top: x; right: x; bottom: x; left: x` and specify `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` behaviors.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}
.header {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.menu-item {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #505050;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content p {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: almost, however if you add menu items to the left menu you will see a scroll bar on it which is not something i want

Comment: i upadted my jsfiddle link, how can i scroll the left div while scrolling the whole page?

Comment: Please rephrase what you're asking.  I don't understand what 'scroll the left div while scrolling the whole page' means.